# Xcode, PHP; Having trouble with retrieving data from PHP/MySQL with SwiftyJSON-master

Tags: php, ios, mysql, swift, xcode

I'm developing an iOS app with Xcode and Swift.

I need to load some data from my MySQL database in my app. I think it's reasonable to do this with JSON (or is there something against it?).

To make it easier I want to use [SwiftyJSON-master](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON).

I found this working code on SO:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var dict = NSDictionary()

    @IBOutlet weak var authorLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var quoteLbl: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        let urlString = "http://api.theysaidso.com/qod.json"

        if let url = NSURL(string: urlString) {

            if let data = try? NSData(contentsOfURL: url, options: []) {

                let json = JSON(data: data)

                print(json)

                let auther = json["contents"]["quotes"][0]["author"].stringValue

                let quote = json["contents"]["quotes"][0]["quote"].stringValue

                authorLbl.text = auther

                quoteLbl.text = quote
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when trying it with my own PHP script it doesn't work.

I think it's because of the different outputs. The (working) PHP script from the SO post I found is like this:

`{"success":{"total":1},"contents":{"quotes":[{"quote":"I put instant coffee in a microwave oven and almost went back in time.","length":"70","author":"Steven Wright","tags":["coffee","funny","humor","thetimes","time"],"category":"funny","id":"LvFg2QsKr_FoCH_lwryQ5geF"}]}}`

Using my own PHP scrip output is like this:
`[{"a":"John Eve","b":"Cupertino","c":"Green","d":"Apple"},{"a":"Sarah Jones","b":"Berlin","c":"Red","d":"Pear"}]`

The syntax seem to bee completely different.

This is my PHP script/code:

```
<?php
$root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
include "$root/config.php";

$query = "SELECT * FROM users";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();

$userData = array();

while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
$userData[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($userData);
?>
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I influence the syntax? Or is it another problem?

*P.S.: Is it reasonable to use this library or is something against it?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update

Your php file returns a correct json format. You can access to the data simply like this:

```
print(json[0]["a"]) // John Eve
print(json[0]["b"]) // Cupertino
// ...
print(json[1]["a"]) // Sarah Jones
print(json[1]["c"]) // Red
```

### Analyzing The JSON Syntax

In pursuit of understanding why is there a difference between the previous two JSON syntaxes, you need to learn about [JSON Syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp).

I will try to explain that to you very briefly.
I know that I'm bad at writing in English, but I'll do my best.

### Curly Braces

The curly braces in json syntax represent a json object like:

```
{"a":"John Eve","b":"Cupertino","c":"Green","d":"Apple"} 
{"a":"Sarah Jones","b":"Berlin","c":"Red","d":"Pear"}
```

### Square Brackets

The square brackets in json syntax represent an array of json objects like:

```
[
 {"a":"John Eve","b":"Cupertino","c":"Green","d":"Apple"},
 {"a":"Sarah Jones","b":"Berlin","c":"Red","d":"Pear"}
]
```

---

So, in the theysaidso's case, the JSON syntax represents a single JSON object that is: 
[image]

The JSON object above has two JSON objects inside of it, the first object is:

```
"success":{"total":1}
```

the second one represents the contents:

[image]

Inside of the content of the JSON object, there is a JSON object called quotes which hold an array of json objects :)

Therefore, when you want to access an object of that nested json object you do this:

```
json["contents"]["quotes"][0]["author"].stringValue
```

In the above code you say: 
return a property of string type called "author" -["author"]- that is in a json object at index of 0 -["quotes"][0]- in the quotes array in the contents object -["contents"]- in my json object -json-!

---

As for your case, you have a single json object that is an array of JSON objects:
[image]

Therefore, when you want to access an object of that nested JSON object you do this:

```
json[0]["a"]
```

In the above code you say: 
return a property called "a" -["a"]- that is in a json object at index of 0 -json[0]- in the json object array -json-!

---

I hope you can understand what I'm trying to say.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my problem. With my PHP script I'm getting no output in Swift. It think it's because the syntax of my JSON string is different from "theysaidso's" JSON string. E.g. my JSON string has only one pair of `[{}]`. "Theysaidso's" JSON string has this character `{` several times. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: @David My pleasure.

Comment: @David I added more details in the answer.